# how to de-merge column name and data in 1st row when importing a .csv file?

Tags: r

Code:

```
data <- read.csv("./data.csv",header=T)
data
```

Output:

```
   X224786   X578    X871   X9719
1   230034    546     969   10262
2   236562    599     845   10120
```

Expected Output:

```
     A    B   C         D
224786  578 871  9719
230034  546 969 10262
236562  599 845 10120
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, your *.csv file has no header line. So, try:

```
data <- read.csv("./data.csv", header=F)
names(data) <- c("A","B","C","D")
```

Comment: 1)the expected output shown above is extracted from the .csv file, so it has the columns names A,B,C,D for each. 

2)Another problem is that the 1st data row and the header line are merging to form the header line e.g. A 224786 --> X224786. (can be seen in output and expected output). 

3)Also my final row is set to NA automatically. (not shown above)

Answer (score 0):

Try `read.table` instead of `read.csv`. `read.csv` requires commas between each field.